# multiple definition of __vector_11’ arduino compiling problem

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

i'm using two libraries
**PCM.h** for playing audio and
**Servo.h** to control a servo motore

while compiling the project i'm getting this issue:

```
“libraries\PCM\PCM.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function startPlayback': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of __vector_11’
```

libraries\Servo\avr\Servo.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.”

my board: Arduino duino uno

Arduino IDE version: 2.0.2

my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <PCM.h>

Servo Myservo;

int pos=0;


const unsigned char sample[] PROGMEM = {
126, 126, 126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127,  };
**strong text**
void setup()
{
 Myservo.attach(4);
 myservo.write(0);
 startPlayback(sample, sizeof(sample));
}

void loop()
{
// other logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making more research i found out that, There is a solution for this problem by switching library from using “Servo.h” To “PWMServo.h”.

All you need to do is to install [pwmservo](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/pwmservo/) and #include <PWMServo.h> instead off #include <Servo.h> while keeping all your code as it is and this will solve your problem,

Happy crafting.